# Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Path' because it is an empty string

Tags: powershell, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-cloudwatch

I am trying to run custom script on windows AWS AMI. The steps I am using is as given here:
    http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/DeveloperGuide/mon-scripts-powershell.html
My Instance is already associated with IAM role and credential file path is set.

I am trying to run following command in power-shell:
    .\mon-put-metrics-mem.ps1 -mem_util -mem_used -mem_avail -page_avail -page_used -page_util -memory_units Megabytes

The error I am getting is:

```
Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Path' because it is an empty string.
```

Answer (score 0):

Your script is not able to see AWS_CREDENTIAL_FILE env var.

So try loading ur credential file

```
setx AWS_CREDENTIAL_FILE C:\aws\myCredentialFile.txt'
```

Then **open a new powershell window** because if you attempt to run it in the same window, it will not see the AWS_CREDENTIAL_FILE env var. Now try running

```
.\mon-put-metrics-mem.ps1 -mem_util -mem_used -mem_avail -page_avail -page_used -page_util -memory_units Megabytes -verbose
```